# How to find and format cells that have text in a certain range?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to search a column and do something to all cells with text, in that column, skipping blank cells.

Specifically
- Move cells if they have text from column G back 4 columns in the same row.
- Format text as Center/Bold/Arial 10.
- Change the color of the cells in columns A-F in the same row of the text I moved.

I can do this for one cell using the VBA below **but I would like to do it as a loop for all the cells in that column**.

```
Sub back_5_format()

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, -5).Range("A1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 5).Range("A1").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.ClearContents
    
' Format Cells Orange

    ActiveCell.Offset(0, -6).Range("A1:F1").Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 49407
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    
' Format Cell Font, Size and Bold
    
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Range("A1").Select
    
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        .WrapText = True
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With
    
    With Selection.Font
        .Name = "Arial"
        .Size = 10
        .Strikethrough = False
        .Superscript = False
        .Subscript = False
        .OutlineFont = False
        .Shadow = False
        .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight1
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .ThemeFont = xlThemeFontNone
    End With
    
    Selection.Font.Bold = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Research `Range.Find` and `Range.FindNext`.

Comment: I would be very grateful to know the syntax for "If cell contains any text"

Answer (score 0):

You can address a cell by its coordinates or a range by its name. `Cells(1, "A")` is the cell and `Range("A1")` is the range.

You can also address a cell by its index number in the cells collection. You can create a collection of the cells in a range or of all the cells in a worksheet. `Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, "A")` addresses `Sheet1!A1. Range("A1:F1").Cells(1)` addresses the first cell in A1:F1, which, by chance, would also be A1. But in a range C12:E23 it would be C12.

You can select any range, be it one cell or many. `Cells(1, "A").Select` selects A1. `Sheet1!A1. Range("A1:F1").Cells(1).Select` would have the same effect only because A1 is the frist cell of Range("A1:F1"). By selecting a cell or range that cell or range becomes the `Selection` object. The code below will print the address of the *Selection* to the Immediate pane. The `Selection` is a range. The address is $A$1 in this case.

```
Cells(1, "A").Select
Debug.Print Selection.Address          ' prints $A$1
```

Of course, `Cells(1, "A")` is a single cell but you could still ask for the address of its first cell. `Cells(1, "A").Cells(1).Address` will give the same result.

After you *Select* a cell that cell becomes the `ActiveCell`. But only one cell can be active at a time. By default Excel will activate the first cell of the `Selection` range. In the example below A1 is the ActiveCell by default.

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:F1").Select
Debug.Print ActiveCell.Address        ' prints $A$1
Selection.Cells(2).Activate
Debug.Print ActiveCell.Address        ' prints $B$1
```

Finally, yes. You can specify a cell from a range of cells by its coordinates (row and column). `Range("A1:C10").Cells(1, 1)` would be the same as `Range("A1:C10").Cells(1)` or A1 but `Range("A1:C10").Cells(2, 1)` wouldn't be the same as `Range("A1:C10").Cells(2)`. the latter would return $B$1, the former $A$2. This game can be extended to specify `Range("A1:C10").Range("A1")` but here "A1" merely specifies Cells(1, 1) and any similarity with sheet coordinates is purely coincidental because it's the range A1:C10 that's being divided into cells and not the entire worksheet.

Now, if you reverse-engineer `ActiveCell.Offset(0, -5).Range("A1")` you would have to start by saying you don't know which cell is active. But from wherever that is, you count 0 rows down and 5 columns to the left and take the first cell from the first row of the range that you would then have. Of course that cell is `ActiveCell.Offset(0, -5)`. Since the ActiveCell is always only a single cell, the resultant Offset range must also be a single cell and the first cell of the first row of a single cell is that same single cell.

However, you don't need to select it. Once you know which cell you are talking about you can read from it or write to it. You can therefore also check if it contains anything. The code below would do that.

```
If ActiveCell.Offset(0, -5).Value = "" Then
    Debug.Print "The cell is empty"
Else If ActiveCell.Offset(0, -5).Value = "Hello" Then
    Debug.Print "The cell contains 'Hello'"
End If
```

Of course, as you now know, nobody would ever use that code because nobody would ever want to check the contents of a cell which he doesn't know where it is. Nor would any programmer *Select* a range in order to use its `Selection` object. In Excel, the *Range* object is more powerful than the *Selection* object. You need to know the Range in order to define the Selection: then why not use the range straight away? Here's an example.

```
With Range("A1:F1").Interior
    .Pattern = xlSolid
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 49407
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With
```

Comment: Thank you Variatus, very helpful info there. Do you by any chance know how to ask if a cell has text in it. I would like to say, If ActiveCell.Value = [any text at].  For example if it has the letters ABC or hljhjQUSYGJ or just A.

Comment: Use the Instr() function, like, `If Instr(ActiveCell.Value, "ABC") Then`. This will return True if "ABC" is found in any location in the cell's value. `If Instr(ActiveCell.Value, "ABC") = 1 Then` would test if the value starts with "ABC".

Answer (score -1):

I found the very simple code which was the most essential. Referencing cells with text.
Here it is in a simple code with a message box.

```
Sub Reference_Cell_if_Contains_Text()
If ActiveCell.Value > 0 Then
Msgbox("This Cell Has Something in it!")
End If
End Sub
```

Now I need to learn how to create a loop for this to go down the whole column.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to write the code using a For Each/Next argument. Here is the code:

```
Sub Format_Cells_if_contains_text_in_range()


Dim Cell As Range

For Each Cell In Range("G1:G200")
    If Cell.Value > 0 Then
    Cell.Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Selection.Copy
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, -5).Range("A1").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
            :=False, Transpose:=False
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 5).Range("A1").Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Selection.ClearContents

' Format Cells Orange

        ActiveCell.Offset(0, -6).Range("A1:F1").Select
        With Selection.Interior
            .Pattern = xlSolid
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .Color = 49407
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .PatternTintAndShade = 0
        End With

' Format Cell Font, Size and Bold

        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Range("A1").Select

        With Selection
            .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
            .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
            .WrapText = True
            .Orientation = 0
            .AddIndent = False
            .IndentLevel = 0
            .ShrinkToFit = False
            .ReadingOrder = xlContext
            .MergeCells = False
        End With

        With Selection.Font
            .Name = "Arial"
            .Size = 10
            .Strikethrough = False
            .Superscript = False
            .Subscript = False
            .OutlineFont = False
            .Shadow = False
            .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
            .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight1
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .ThemeFont = xlThemeFontNone
        End With

        Selection.Font.Bold = True

    End If
Next Cell

End Sub
```